Inequality of operator norm. Theorem of bounded linear extention
This is Theorem 2.7-11 in Kreyszig's Introductory functional analysis with applications:

Let $T:\mathcal{D}(T) \rightarrow Y$ be a bounded linear operator where the domain $\mathcal{D}(t)$ lies in a normed space $X$ and $Y$ is a Banach space. Then $T$ has an extention $\tilde{T}:\overline{\mathcal{D}}(T) \rightarrow Y$ where $\tilde{T}$ is a bounded linear operator of norm $\|\tilde{T}\| = \|T\|$.

I have a very basic question concerning the proof of this theorem. I just sketch briefly the parts of the proof I need and next I write my question. Of course since we are interested in $\overline{\mathcal{D}}(T)$, we take any $x$ in it and thus there is a sequence in the domain such that $x_n\rightarrow x$. One can also find that the equivalent sequence in the image converges, i.e. $Tx_n\rightarrow Tx$. Also, it is proven that $\tilde{T}$ is an extention of $T$. Now, since $T$ is bounded, one has
$$
\|Tx_n\| \leq \|T\| \|x_n\|,\; (*)
$$
and, quoting the text

... let $n\rightarrow \infty$. Then $Tx_n\rightarrow y=\tilde{T}x$. Since $x\mapsto \|x\|$ defines a continuous mapping, we thus obtain $$\|\tilde{T}x\|\leq\|T\||x\| $$.

My simple question is, why do we need to say that the mapping $x\mapsto \|x\|$ is continuous? Is this needed in order to (*) to be fulfilled? equivalently, what will happen if such map was not continuous?

You need the fact that $x_n \to x$ implies $|x_n|\to |x|$. That is exactly continuity of $x \to |x|$.
